# Excel Split Date Range Grand Total into Daily Totals

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, split, dataset

I am struggling with a formula, I tried Index Match formulas with sum and it didn't work at all.

I have a dataset with names that has a start and end date with the total time in decimal between them. I want to split this data in daily totals for each name but it cannot exceed the daily 24 hour mark.

The date 24 hours goes from 07:00 to 07:00 so for a it should calculate the first day from 2021/01/01 07:00 to 2021/01/02 07:00, any time outside that range should not be added to the sum.

I have created an example below:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be simpler for you to develop a VBA or Power Query solution.  Since this is not a free coding service, edit your question to show your efforts and any questions that may arise in your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree. However since I have a bit of time available being in lockdown, and there is a standard solution that can be tweaked slightly, I might as well post it.

Comment: My apologies gents, I have tried a few attempts but haven't had the time to post all my attempts, @TomSharpe, Your solution works and I have tweaked it to work during other times as well. I will upvote and approve as the correct answer, Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on the standard [overlap formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-date-overlap-in-days)

```
=MAX(MIN(end1,end2)-MAX(start1,start2)+1,0)
```

re-cast as an array formula and altered to allow for the 7am-7am time frame:

```
=SUM((A$2:A$8=I2)*TEXT(IF(C$2:C$8<(H2+31/24),C$2:C$8,H2+31/24)-IF(B$2:B$8>(H2+7/24),B$2:B$8,H2+7/24),"general;\0")*24)
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely a great formula to go with this solution. Thank you Tom for your time and assistance.